# Change angular2 Route Name

Tags: angular

Is there any way I can change the route name of a route dynamically? I am displaying name of the activated at the header of my application. I want to change the name of my route dynamically. I am currently initialising the route something like this

```
{ path: 'Customer', component: TotalDetailsComponent, canActivate: [CanActivateViaGuard], canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard],data:{name:'Customer'} },
```

How can I change the route name dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the name dynamically but you can pass parameters dynamically in route. I think you are looking for dynamically changing parameter like this:

```
{path: 'product/:id', component: ProductDetailComponentParam}
```